# Clicking an element having same class name as others

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to locate and click an element which is having same className as other elements. I am unable to differentiate that element from other to click that element. Here is the HTML code of that element:

```
<a href="/category/men/N-fh7rea" class="accord-header">
  Men
</a>
```

In this code, classname is same as others elements and text "Men" is also same. So made an Xpath of this:

```
//a[@class='accord-header' AND contains(text(),'Men') ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Tweak the *xpath* a bit and use :

```
//a[@class='accord-header' and @href='/category/men/N-fh7rea']
```

You can get more granular and use :

```
//a[@class='accord-header' and @href='/category/men/N-fh7rea' and contains(.,'Men')]
```

You can alos use :

```
//a[@class='accord-header' and @href='/category/men/N-fh7rea'][normalize-space()='Men']
```

Comment: what does "[normalize-space()='Men']" do?

Answer (score 0):

if you can't find any difference you can always count whith one, from the same objects interest you. If its for example 3rd element, save all of them as a list using findElements, and then get third element from it.

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='accord-header' and @href='/category/men/N-fh7rea' and contains(.,'Men')]"));
WebElement elementThatYouLookedFor = elems.get(2);
```

If You need to click all of elements of this kind just use foreach loop:

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='accord-header' and @href='/category/men/N-fh7rea' and contains(.,'Men')]"));
for(WebElement we : elems){
we.click(); //or any other operation
}
```